# Erro ao criar tabelas no mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Estou tentando criar essas tabelas pelo mysql porém está dando erro. Criei o relacionamento entre as tabelas no MySQl Workbench. Alguém consegue me dar uma ajuda?

ERRO:

```
Static analysis:

1 errors were found during analysis.

A comma or a closing bracket was expected. (near "VISIBLE" at position 572)
```

Comando SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `webimoveis`.`tb_cadastro_cliente` ( `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `nome` VARCHAR(55) NOT NULL, `sobrenome` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL, `cnpj` VARCHAR(55) NOT NULL, `razao social` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, `rua` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, `complemento` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL, `bairro` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL, `cidade` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL, `estado` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL, `logo_cliente` BLOB NOT NULL, `id_cad` INT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `id_cad`), INDEX `fk_tb_cadastro_cliente_tb_imoveis_idx` (`id_cad` ASC) VISIBLE) ENGINE = MyISAM
```

Mensagens do MySQL : Documentação

```
#1064 - Você tem um erro de sintaxe no seu SQL próximo a 'VISIBLE)
  ENGINE = MyISAM' na linha 15
```

Código:

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `webimoveis`.`tb_cadastro_cliente` (
      `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `nome` VARCHAR(55) NOT NULL,
      `sobrenome` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
      `cnpj` VARCHAR(55) NOT NULL,
      `razao social` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
      `rua` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
      `complemento` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
      `bairro` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
      `cidade` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
      `estado` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
      `logo_cliente` BLOB NOT NULL,
      `id_cad` INT NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `id_cad`),
      INDEX `fk_tb_cadastro_cliente_tb_imoveis_idx` (`id_cad` ASC) VISIBLE)
      ENGINE = MyISAM;

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `webimoveis`.`tb_imoveis` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `titulo_imovel` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `numero` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `bairro` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `cidade` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `estado` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `area_util` INT NOT NULL,
  `area_total` INT NOT NULL,
  `n_quartos` INT NOT NULL,
  `n_banheiros` INT NOT NULL,
  `n_vagas` INT NOT NULL,
  `descricao` LONGTEXT NOT NULL,
  `valor` FLOAT(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `status` INT NULL,
  `tipo` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = MyISAM
```

Comment: Qual a versão do MySQL? Por que precisa informar o `visible` ali?

Comment: A versão é 5.7.14, eu criei o relacionamento pelo SQL Workbench dei um copy to clipboard e joguei no mysql direto. Já veio do workbench com o visible.

Comment: O Maria DB  10.2 é baseado no MySQL 5.7([KB da versões do MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-versions/)) e portanto não suporta as palavras chaves `VISIBLE` e `INVISIBLE` para definir a visibilidade dos indices. É só tirar o `VISIBLE` que funciona. O problema é sempre que gerar o SQL o Workbench sempre vai colocar  o atributo de visibilidade e você vai ter que remover manualmente.

Comment: Obrigado agora funcionou!